# Как назначить цену приложению в Google Play Console?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

Как назначить цену приложению в **Google Play Console**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. При заливке приложения не забыть сразу указать, что оно **Платное**. Иначе Бесплатное потом невозможно будет перевести в Платное - так задумано! )
2. Зайти в **Настройки** своего акаунта
3. Зайти в **Шаблоны цен**
4. Создать **Новый шаблон цен**
5. Вернуться в приложение.
6. Зайти в **Настройки страницы приложения** > **Цены и Распространение** и назначить нужный шаблон своему приложению

Рис. к пункту 2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рис. к пунктам 3,4:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]